# Simple code written in beautifulsoup does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to learn beautiful soup. I ran the following code in visual code. But there was no successful answer. The terminal does not show an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam?ac=1"
page = requests.get(url) 
# print(page)

soup =BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all("section", class_='listing-search-item')

for list in lists:
    title = list.find("a", class_="listing-search-item__link--title").text
    price = list.find("div", class_="listing-search-item__price").text
    area = list.find("li", class_="illustrated-features__item--surface-area").text
    rooms = list.find("li", class_="illustrated-features__item--number-of-rooms").text

    info =[title,price,area,rooms]
    print(info)
```

The following is what is shown in the terminal after running this.

Help me solve this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCGFC.png

Comment: when you `print(page)` it shows 200?

Comment: You have a typo.  Your last line should be `print(info)`, not `print(lists)`.  That fixes it.

Comment: @AlbertoHanna Yes. it's show 200

Comment: @TimRoberts oh sorry. I corrected it. but result is same

Comment: You need to be printing `page.text`.  It absolutely did work once, but their web site has code to detect and block bots like yours.  If you make too many requests, they make you solve a CAPTCHA.  That's why it fails for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can't scrape data from sites with such bot?

Comment: works fine for me. You may need to add a user-agent in the headers. That sometimes will override any bot blockage

Comment: @TipVisor You can scrape it a couple of times, until their bot detector fires, then you'll have to wait until it expires, whatever that time is.  Remember, they are actively trying to prevent you from stealing their copyrighted material, as you are trying to do.

Comment: Try to use playwright or selenium.